Iptables does not capture bridged packets
I have a linux (kernel 6.6) with eth0 and eth1. I create a br0 from them. The linux is between a pc and a router. I want to capture tcp packets on the br0 with destination ip 190.191.60.136 and dport 55555 and change the payload by python script using netfilterqueue and put it back on br0 to get out from linux. The rest of traffic has to traverse br0 normally.
I set up: 
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d 190.191.60.136 -p tcp --dport 55555 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1

but does not capture any packet.
It seems iptables is not able to capture bridged packets. Do I need to configure something else on linux?
How can I do it ? Any different solution?

Do I need to configure something else on linux? Yes, nftables (bridge table), or ebtables (which is really a "translator" for the former on most distros these days, I think).

How configure ebtables?

No idea. I don't even know what NFQUEUE is/does or whether it is supported in ebtables. There's a chance that you can only use it nftables.

I switched to use nftables instead of iptables. I can capture bridged packets now. In term of performance which one is faster nftables or ebtables? I have intensive traffic (Gb/sec)

As I said, in most distro ebtables would really just translate your commands to an nftable. (In some but fewer cases, you'll be using such a "variant" of iptables as well.)
